# Slickgrid Copy Paste issues

Tags: slickgrid

We are thinking about using `SlickGrid` in our application. I have run into a few issues with the copy paste functionality.  We are using the ExternalCopyManager plugin.

- Copy and paste on an editable grid doesn’t paste multiple cells. It looks like it only pastes the current selected cell.
- When you have `leaveSpaceForNewRows =true` and `enableAddRow` and you paste multiple rows at the end of the grid it only creates 1 row.

Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

SlickGrid doesn't have copy'n'paste.  It has a plugin Slick.CellCopyManager, but it doesn't copy the cells for you.  It fires the copy/paste events and tells you which ranges need to be copied from where and where to.  You still have to implement the actual logic for copying.  It's done in that way because the rules for the actual copying are very application-specific.

Comment: We are using the ExternalCopyManager plugin I was wondering if anyone using the plugin have suggestions using it in the way we are implementing it.

Comment: You should contact the author of that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

[Check this example out](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-spreadsheet.html): you can copy/paste multiple cells.

[image]

First, double click a cell to edit its contents.  Do that with multiple cells.

Then, right click a cell and WITHOUT RELEASING (mouse left still down), drag the mouse to cover a range of cells (their backgrounds will turn yellowish).  Release the left click.

CTRL+C will copy this range.  These cells are now blueish.

Select the range that you will paste to and CTRL+V.  If your paste range is smaller than your copy range, only the selected paste range will receive new cell calues.